# Heroku, PHP and precomplie lesscss

Tags: php, heroku, less

I wrote a simple PHP app with CSS code written in less, using the client-side less.js script to parse the less file. We are deploying the app to Heroku and its working as expected.

What I would like to do is to configure Heroku to compile the .less files in to .css files as part of the push process. So I can include .css file instead of the .less+node.js combo. From what I have read, this should be possible but have no found samples specific to PHP on Heroku.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to my question by using [lessphp](http://lessphp.gpeasy.com) and updating my composer.json file as follows:

```
{
  "require": {
    "php": "~5.6.0",
    "oyejorge/less.php": "~1.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "vendor/bin/lessc css/style.less > css/style.css"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "vendor/bin/lessc css/style.less > css/style.css"
        ]
    }
```

}